# Augment latex citation with specific table (or figure) reference

Tags: latex

How do I include a specific table within a latex citation, i.e., what's the syntax?  In other words, I'd like to cite table 11.1 in the "Handbook of Hydrology" by David Maidment.  In my BibTex text file, the reference is:

```
@book{maidment1993,
    Author = {Maidment, David R},
    Isbn = {0-07-039732-5},
    Publisher = {McGraw-Hill},
    Address = {New York, USA},
    Title = {Handbook of Hydrology},
    Year = {1993}}
```

and so in the tex file that invokes this reference, it's easy enough to add `...\citep{maidment1993}...`, but if I want the output to also include table 11.1, as in "...(Table 1.1; Maidment, 1993)." and not merely "(Maidment, 1993)", how do I do that in the .tex file?  I tried `\citep{Table 11.1 maidment1993}`, but not surprisingly, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the table as optional argument. For example with biblatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite[Table 11.1]{knuth:ct}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```